# How to pass additional data during OAuth registration in next-auth?

Tags: next-auth

My project uses `GitHubProvider` and `GoogleProvider` to allow login and registration, while `PrismaAdapter` is handling persistent storage of users' data.
Like most websites, I would like mine to have a separate form for login where only simple provider buttons can be present, while the registration form will collect additional data about a user - like preferred user name and such.

How can I make a button using `signIn` function(or there is an alternative?) to pass additional data through an OAuth adapter to a database provider, which will save them while creating a user?

I know that we can pass `authorizationParams` to `signIn` but that works only for `CredentialsProvider`.
I thought that maybe I could create a cookie and make its value be attached in the `signIn` callback, but I don't see any way to get access to cookies from there.
I also thought of making a custom adapter, but `createUser` method only receives `user` object.